# How to know which ajax file or function is called for action

Tags: functions, ajax, filesystem

I want to know which ajax file or function is called for action.

For example, if i enter some keyword in filtering, it performs some ajax action. When i searched for ajax file chrome developer tools network tab, it shows me the admin-ajax.php.

But i want to know which file or functions performs it exactly. Please let me know, is there any plugin or solution for this

Comment: when the file admin-ajax.php is called with a parameter `action=ACTION`, theses hooks are called : `wp_ajax_ACTION` is user is connected and `wp_ajax_nopriv_ACTION` if user is not connected